# Should I hydrate a domain object using a EF Entity?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

There are a number of questions about this but, as far as I see, none that address this question.

Is it wrong for a domain object to consume an EF Entity to hydrate it? On one hand, this is very similar to a memento. An EF Entity can be treated as a DTO or an active record.

On the other hand, this seems to couple the domain to the DAL (as EF Entities could be considered DAO's)

**EDIT** To clarify what I'm asking about here... I have a Domain Model that isn't aware of my data access layer. The Repositories return my DO's but those DO's are put together using DTO's. The DTO's are property bags build specifically to be used by repositories to hydrate the DOs. So even though my DO's don't depend on the EF Entities, they depend on DTOs whose sole job is to be mapped from EF entities... so I've created code solely to facility hydration. This seems a little smelly to me.

I am absolutely not asking whether the DO should use an EF to persist itself. I'm asking whether or not I can *read* from an EF Entity to hydrate the DO.

Comment: Generally your conversion from EF entity to domain entity would be done in your persistence layer, in a repository method.  Your domain entity would know nothing about things like EF.

Comment: @Matthew why would you do that ? What are the benefits if it couples the Domain to the DAL ?

Comment: @guillaume31 No benefits. What is my alternative? I create a DTO, which is a deep copy of the Entity, and use that?

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips Agreed, and the entity is a POCO... The problem I'm thinking is of what *should* I use, then?

Comment: @Matthew How about mapping to your domain objects directly with EF Code First + fluent API ? Also, "hydrate" means to populate an object based on data from a database, I've never seen it used the other way around. What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: @guillaume31 My domain doesn't align with my db layout. The tiers are separated. When I hydrate my DO's now I tend to do it using a memento that is a DTO which often contains relevant properties of a few EF entities. My repository packages them into the memento and then hydrates the DO. So I am creating DTO "copies" of EF entities already.

Comment: A little code would make things clearer. But if I get you well, you're trying to preserve domain object encapsulation with a Memento pattern, but the problem is that the memento class the DO restores its state with is part of the DAL ? Why not make the memento part of the domain then ? Similarly to the State object here : https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=879

Comment: @guillaume31 My Memento isn't data-aware... but it's more or less a DTO made from EF entity objects.

Comment: A memento is meant to represent a past state, so a database DTO doesn't really fit the usage.  Your database might momentarily be out of sync with the object in memory, but that's not the purpose of a database, and that state is temporary (between changes and commit).

An exception would be a snapshot in an event-sourced database, where the object in the database is supposed to represent state at a past time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't persist EF Entities past the data service layer.

It's partially a fault of conflicting names.  Even if you never intend for your product to be on a non-EF platform, however, you should abstract away the details of how it's persisted (the EF structure) from the actual object and its methods.

I've had personal experience on several projects in the .NET world that used EF generated objects all the way to the ASP .NET layer, and it never ends well.  When you do that, you're introducing enough of a coupling that your application goes from n-tier to 1-tier in reality.

Here's a better way to do it -

Create a IPersistenceService interface, with your methods (Save, Get, etc).

Create an implementation for entity framework - EFPersistenceService.

In each of your methods, have the EF object map to your entity model - you can use automapper or other technologies to do so trivially.

The rest of your application should only talk to the database through IPersistenceService (application of always program to an interface rule).

If it seems like overkill - ask yourself how you'll improve performance by splitting databases in the future (CQRS), or if you had to change a specific update to a stored proc for performance reasons?

Comment: That's true, even if it doesn't answer the OP's question as I (am trying to) understand it. And it seems you're basically describing the Repository pattern from DDD, by the way.

Comment: Yes I understand. But the primary difference between your answer and my question is that you're using auto-mapper to hydrate the DO. Ultimately this is a poor solution because it means that the DO cannot be hydrated except via reflection (such as how automapper works)... Without a memento to hydrate it, only a layer which is aware of the mapper can instantiate a DO... Does my question make sense?

Comment: You don't have to use automapper - the whole point of abstracting out persistence into an interface is to allow it to be changed without affecting calling code. 

You can hold your persistence code in a Repository, btw, but it makes more sense to my mind to abstract out the database calls, and have that be a dependency of the repository.